# Is there a keyboard shortcut to access Developer Tools in IE8?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Our company's ERP system runs only in Internet Explorer. When it opens, it chops up Internet Explorer so that you can't right-click or access any file menu items.

I'd like to be able to open the developer tools to inspect some elements on the page. **Is there a keyboard shortcut to access Developer Tools in Internet Explorer 8**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press `F12` on the keyboard to open developer tools while in a web page.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/62284/ie8-developer-tools-wont-open